# Relationship between the two forms

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, checkbox

Methods opening forms :

> form1 --> form2 --> form3

ChecklistBox on the form1 there. How to know the form3  That is active or not?

Comment: That's not an equation. Equations have equal signs in them.

Comment: I think "-->" is supposed to mean "opens"

Answer (score 1):

If the forms you are referencing are [MDI child forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activemdichild.aspx), you could use

```
Form activeChild = this.ActiveMdiChild;
```

else you could use the following code if not using MDI child forms.

```
Form currentForm = Form.ActiveForm;
```

Comment: I want to understand checklist is active or not.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are asking if form 3 is opened. If that is incorrect, please enlighten me.

There are probably dozens of ways to do so, it all depends on what you want to do.

One simple way would be to leave a flag somewhere, say in your Program.cs file:

```
public static bool Form3IsOpen = false;
```

Then:

```
private void Form3_Load(sender object, EventArgs e)
{
    Program.Form3IsOpen = true;
}
```

And:

```
private void Form3_Close(sender object, EventArgs e)
{
    Program.Form3IsOpen = false;
}
```

Supplemental:

You can also keep a reference to your subform:

In form1.cs:

```
private Form2 FormChild;

//In the function that opens the Form2:
FormChild = new Form2();
FormChild.Show();
```

Form2 will have something similar to retain Form3. If one form can open several, just use an array or collection.

Comment: I want to understand checklist is active or not.

Comment: @ups: I don't understand what you mean. Can you elaborate, write more about what you want to accomplish? Perhaps post your code (even if it doesn't work)?

Answer (score 0):

When i usually have many different forms and only one instance to be created, i put them in dictonary and check it if there is a form.

Something like this:

```
 public static Dictonary<string, Form> act_forms_in_app = new Dictonary<string, Form>();
```

now in every forms creation i do it like this

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Name = "Myformname"
//set its properties etc.
frm.Load => (s,ev) { act_forms_in_app.Add(frm.Name, frm);};
frm.Load += new EventHandler(frm_Load);
frm.Disposed => (s, ev) { act_forms_in_app.Remove(frm.Name)};

//your usual form load event handler
public void frm_Load(object sender, EventArguments e)
{
    ...
}
```

somewhere where you want to check

```
Form frm = //Your form object
if(act_forms_in_app.ContainsKey(frm.Name))
{
     //Perform as required
}
```

Comment: I want to understand checklist is active or not.